# Is it possible to detect chrome remote debugger or automation enabled

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-remote-debugging

Is it possible to detect if a website visitors chrome browser is being controlled by another program via the chrome remote debugging (aka DevTools Protocol) protocol?

Is there any other way to detect if a users chrome browser is using the startup parameter --enable-automation besides via the variable navigator.webdriver?

Answer (score 0):

I think bet365 will detect remote debugging somehow so its possible to detect, however not sure how.